Best way to visualize interactions and dependencies of two objects in different systems?
I'm designing the process where a change in the status of Object1 in System1 triggers the creation of Object2 in System2. Then status change in the Object2 can initiate a status change in Object1 and vice versa. (And sometimes it doesn't).
I'm looking for the best way to visualize this workflow, including status sequences for both objects (with alternative paths and loops) as well as the integration points and directional dependencies between the two systems.
Can I use BPMN for this?

Do you mean visualizing the requirements in some design document? Or do you mean visualizing the workflow in the GUI of some productive, running software for controlling the actual workflow? Moreover, I miss a description of what you tried so far and why it did not suit your needs.

... in case you meant the former, you may utilize an UML sequence diagram for this. However, I recommend to refrain from showing loops in this kind of diagram. You may use an activity diagram for showing loops.

The main problem is that there is a rather branchy status model  for the object1, and I need to somehow visualise, how the statuses of the object1 will align with the statuses of the object2 (and they are not matching well), including the points of integration

We cannot help you if you give a description of a simple problem in the question, but then say in the comments "it is far more complicated". Try to edit the question. provide context, more examples, details, maybe a scetch of what you tried and where exactly you hit the limits. Yes, that will require some effort, but otherwise I doubt outsiders like us can give good advice.

Honestly, such design, where objects depend on each other in a circular way is almost always a red flag. Instead of documenting/visualizing this I would suggest to redesign it if possible.


I'm designing the process where a change in the status of Object1 in System1 triggers the creation of Object2 in System2. Then status change in the Object2 can initiate a status change in Object1 and vice versa. (And sometimes it doesn't).

Have you considered something that looks like this:

If you can’t map the states well it may be you haven’t hit on the right design yet. It’s ok to add hidden complexity if it means you can provide a useful abstraction.
Are two objects really enough for this?
